# Deleting non unicode characters python

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am trying to return a request but it is giving me an error that there are non-unicode characters in the string. I am filtering them out but then it makes the string in unicode style which crashes the app with a badly formatted response.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
unfiltered_string = str({'location_id': location.pk, 'name': location.location_name,'address': location.address+', '+location.locality+', '+location.region+' '+location.postcode, 'distance': location.distance.mi, })
filtered_string = str(filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, unfiltered_string)).encode("utf-8")
locations.append(filtered_string)
```

The troubles is it appends a string that looks like

```
{'distance': 4.075068111513138, 'location_id': 1368, 'name': u'Stanford University', 'address': u'450 Serra Mall, Stanford, CA 94305'}
```

when I need the u'string' to just be 'string' like this

```
{'distance': 4.075068111513138, 'location_id': 1368, 'name': 'Stanford University', 'address': '450 Serra Mall, Stanford, CA 94305'}
```

if I try using `string.encode('ascii','ignore')` then I still get

```
"{'location_id': 1368, 'address': u'450 Serra Mall, Stanford, CA 94305', 'distance': 4.075068111513138, 'name': u'Stanford University'}"
```

and now I get extra quotations around the json

Comment: Please show us your *full traceback* and the code that produces the error. I'm sure that what you are doing is not correct for the problem you are facing.

Comment: “when I need the u'string' to just be 'string' like this”—why? You are producing `repr` output via `dict.str()` and this is valid Python literal syntax for Unicode strings. If you are trying to produce some format that is not a Python literal, for example JavaScript, then you shouldn't be using Python `repr` output (consider eg a JSON encoder instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that your goal here is to ignore the unicode specific characters that you've got. I think it's really difficult to say anything definitive without a better explanation in your question, but if you're looking to get a "plain" string instead of a unicode one I would suggest using the `ascii` codec for encoding instead of `utf-8`.

```
<str>.encode('ascii')
```

If you want to remove the other characters, the `encode` function takes an optional second argument allowing you to ignore all characters that the specified codec can't handle:

```
<str>.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a type-cast in Python, using `str()` produces a new object of the `str()` type provided the `unicode` string can be encoded with the default codec. Using `str()` means you are relying on `unicode_version` to be encodable to bytes with the ASCII codec; you probably want to use an explicit codec instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's totally fair, sorry, I think I jumped the gun on the answer a little bit before seeing that there was an explicit `utf-8` encoding above, revising now.

Comment: @TylerRice It's still very, very hard to give accurate feedback without a fuller picture of what you're trying to do. If you're just trying to get rid of the `u`, you can still do str(<u'text'>), but I have a feeling that there's more to it than that.