# TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 618.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, typeerror

I've been trying to implement this ML Linear Model into my dataset. (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimator/linear) 
Language: Python 3.8.3
Lİbraries: 
TensorFlow 2.4.0
Numpy: 1.19.3
Pandas
Matplotlib
and the others:

```
import os
import sys

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import clear_output
from six.moves import urllib
```

```
import tensorflow.compat.v2.feature_column as fc
import tensorflow as tf
```

ss1517 is the name of my dataset. It is a CSV file with 4116 rows and 20 columns and has lots of NaN values( There is no column that hasn't NaN value)

```
traindata = ss1517.iloc[0:2470,:] # 60 % of my dataset is splitted by training set
evaldata = ss1517.iloc[2470:4116, :] # 40 % of my dataset is splitted by eval set
ytrain = traindata.pop("AvgOfMajor N")
yeval = evaldata.pop("AvgOfMajor N")
```

CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS are the categorical columns in my dataset. 
NUMERIC_COLUMNS are the numeric columns in my dataset.

```
CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS = ['Location Name', 'Location Code', 'Borough', 'Register', 'Building Name', 'Schools in Building', 'ENGroupA', 'RangeA']
NUMERIC_COLUMNS = ['Geographical District Code', '# Schools', 'Major N', 'Oth N', 'NoCrim N', 'Prop N', 'Vio N', 'AvgOfOth N', 'AvgOfNoCrim N', 'AvgOfProp N', 'AvgOfVio N']

feature_columns = []#Sadece linear regression'u eğitmek için kullanıyoruz
for feature_name in CATEGORICAL_COLUMNS:
  vocabulary = traindata[feature_name].unique()
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(feature_name, vocabulary))
for feature_name in NUMERIC_COLUMNS:
  feature_columns.append(tf.feature_column.numeric_column(feature_name, dtype=tf.float32))
```

```
def make_input_fn(data_df, label_df, num_epochs=10, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  def input_function():# inner function, this will be returned.
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(data_df), label_df)) # Create tf.data.Dataset object with data and its label
    if shuffle:
      ds = ds.shuffle(1000) # randomize order of data
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)
    return ds # return a batch of dataset
  return input_function # return the input_function

train_input_fn = make_input_fn(traindata, ytrain) 
eval_input_fn = make_input_fn(evaldata, yeval, num_epochs=1, shuffle=False)
```

```
linear_est = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns)
linear_est.train(train_input_fn) #train
result = linear_est.evaluate(eval_input_fn) #get model metrics/stats by testing on testing data

clear_output() #clears console output
print(result["accuracy"]) #the result variable is simply dict of stats about our model
```

I have this error(`TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 618.0`) every time I tried to fill the NaN values with `df.fillna(method="ffill")` ,  `df.fillna(method="bfill")` , `df.fillna(value = 0)`, or`df.fillna(value="randomstringvalues)`.
I also tried to drop the NaN values with `df.dropna()` 
Needless to say, when I tried to run my code with NaN values it couldn't work. 
I have two questions. 
The first one, how could I handle my NaN values so that I won't see this error (`TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got 618.0`) in the future? 
The second one, how can I get rid of this error and implement my dataset into this model swiftly? 
P.S.: I am positive that I did not make any typos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MY guess is that you have some non-unicode characters in your data. Non unicode characters are like this: � ä

anything that is not a letter, number or symbol.
you have two options here, to find all these characters and [replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3870084/how-to-decode-a-non-unicode-character-in-python) them with something else or [remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28649795/deleting-non-unicode-characters-python/28649893) them.

Or you can use a proper encoding when reading the csv file. [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

```
data = pandas.read_csv(myfile, encoding='utf-8', quotechar='"', delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your data so this is a guess. Open your .csv file and search for 618.0. Perhaps, some lines don't have all the expected values and the parser is trying to load a numerical value where a categorical one is expected.
Another way to see if you have "format" issues is by opening your csv in excel and see if all lines are properly formatted.

Comment: My CSV file is the combination of these two: 
 https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/rear-wh5i/rows.xml?accessType=DOWNLOAD , https://data.cityofnewyork.us/api/views/44t3-dj6x/rows.csv?accessType=DOWNLOAD . I combined them like this : ```ss1517 = pd.concat([ss1516,ss1617],axis=0,join="inner") ```     I searched and couldn't find anything about the 618.0                                                        As you can see, lines are proper enough for a CSV file( Not strictly formatted like XLSX file but formatted with coma)